# Allowing admin of rails site to edit html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the whole admin backend setup, but I need to add a feature were admins can either edit the HTML of the site, or if easier edit just the text around the site. The main idea is to have the admin edit the form labels through the backend. Was wondering which is the best direction to go with?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Rails internationalization support for things like this in the past: static bits of text that admins, non-technical stakeholders, business people, etc want to tweak and tweak, and I want to enable them to do it quickly (and without bothering me to fix a typo they would)

For the being able to edit form labels you could/should use Rails Internationalization Support for form fields. Here's a super [brief intro to this](http://fredwu.me/post/434076573/rails-tip-making-i18n-forms-the-easy-way), but there are better documentations to dive into.

[Rails Internationalization support allows for more than just storing keys in YAML files](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) - there are few different ways to do it. There's also [CopyCopter](http://copycopter.com/) an open source admin website for internationalization keys.

As far as having non-technical people edit other parts of your site, internationalization could help here too: allowing folks to change whole phrases/blocks of text in your app.

For example, instead of hard coding, "Welcome to the site" in a `.html.erb` file you do `<%= t :welcome %>`. An admin can edit the `welcome` internationalization key and change it to something more appropriate, "Yar! We be welcoming you to the site" if you want to go pirate theme. Or Whatever.

It also gives you internationalization structure for free: makes it easy for admins to edit the English of the site, but you have all the infrastructure for making a French version of the site too - just get a translator to fill in French internationalization values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could realize that with following editor:

- Github: https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury
- Demo: http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/
- Railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor (maybe outdated)